# how to show thai characters in html

Tags: html

```
<div class="gbz_smsblock" id="TH">
    <div class="gbz_smsblock_header"> <img src="images/growbiz_logo.png" class="logogrowbiz">
        <h3>เรียกใช้ผู้ช่วยอัจฉริยะของคุณ</h2>
            <p>เปิดลิงก์ใน SMS ที่ส่ง<i style="color:#000">(กับ Growbiz)</i><br>
                เพื่อตรวจสอบและเปิดตัวภายใน 60 วินาที</p>

    </div>


    <div class="sms_numberblock">
        <p>SMS ถูกส่งไปที่</p>

        <!-- <p><a href="" class="sms_btn">Re-send SMS</a>  <a href="" class="sms_btn">Change HP num</a> </!-->
    </div>


    <div class="smscontentblock">
        <p>อนุญาต / เปิดใช้งานการแจ้งเตือนสำหรับ 
            <b><i>Growbiz</i></b>&nbsp; อนุญาตให้<br> 
            ผู้ช่วยที่ชาญฉลาดในการทำงานกับคุณได้อย่างราบรื่น</p>
        <div class="bizimgblock">
            <div class="sms_overtext"> Growbiz คือ<br>
                แล้วใน<br>
                โทรศัพท์ของคุณ!</div>
            <img class="" src="images/sms_pic.png" width="100%">
        </div>
        <p class="powerdby"><a href=""><u>เรียนรู้เพิ่มเติมเกี่ยวกับแอป Growbiz</u></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: What exactly are your issues with this HTML fragment? Please [edit] them into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two tags to the head part of your html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="th" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

If above does not work for you then try to add the below line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-874">
```